# How to obtain curve or line graph based on benchmark result?

Tags: r, ggplot2, benchmarking

I want to generate nice line graph or curve based on benchmark result. I used `rbenchmark` packages to evaluate list of function. However, I intend to generate line graph or curve where X axis shows selected csv files (two or three files), Y axis shows run time. How can I get desired line graph or scatter plot, or curve graph based on benchmark result ? Can anyone point me out how to do this easily? How can I achieve my desired plot ? Any idea ?

Note that I tried `rbenchmark` package to produce benchmarkk result in this way :

```
benchmark(
    s1=myFunc1,
    s2=myFunc2,
    s3=myFunc3,
    ...
    s10=myFunc10,
    order="elapsed", replications=10
)
```

Mini example :

to reproduce the benchmark result, Here is data.frame :

```
benchResult <- data.frame(
    test=c("s5","s1","s6","s9","s2","s3","s4","s7","s8","s10"),
    replications=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
    elapsed=c(0.10,0.11,0.30,0.32,0.75,0.98,3.43,8.07,13.22,30.48),
    relative=c(1.0,1.1,3.0,3.2,7.5,9.8,34.3,80.7,132.2,304.8),
    user.self=c(0.11,0.03,0.30,0.33,0.75, 0.73,3.36,8.07,13.21,27.70),
    sys.self=c(0.00,0.02,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.09,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.31)
)
```

I got this benchmark result:

```
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
5    s5           10    0.10      1.0      0.11     0.00         NA        NA
1    s1           10    0.11      1.1      0.03     0.02         NA        NA
6    s6           10    0.30      3.0      0.30     0.00         NA        NA
9    s9           10    0.32      3.2      0.33     0.00         NA        NA
2    s2           10    0.75      7.5      0.75     0.00         NA        NA
3    s3           10    0.98      9.8      0.73     0.09         NA        NA
4    s4           10    3.43     34.3      3.36     0.00         NA        NA
7    s7           10    8.07     80.7      8.07     0.00         NA        NA
8    s8           10   13.22    132.2     13.21     0.00         NA        NA
10  s10           10   30.48    304.8     27.70     0.31         NA        NA
```

How can I get nice line graph or curve based on this benchmark result ? How can I make this happen by using `ggplot2` ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: where are you the storing number of csv's, you plan to use on the x-axis?

Comment: @NathanDay sorry for my confusing post. csv files are placed in `inst/extdat` directory. I used three csv files as an input for `myFunc1`, continue with `myFunc2`, and so on. I am trying to see how can I get nice plot based on this benchmark result. How can I get explicit curve or line graph ? Any chance to obtain intuitive plot based on the output of benchmark ? Thank you :)

Comment: just use any of the bench mark times as your y variable, `geom_smooth(aes(y = elapsed, x = num_csvs))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has two parts:

1. The `microbenchmark` package includes an `autoplot` method for `ggplot2`
2. Code to plot the given `benchResult` data frame

### 1. `microbenchmark` package

The `autoplot` method uses `ggplot2` to produce a more legible graph of microbenchmark timings. For example,

```
tm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rchisq(100, 0),
  rchisq(100, 1),
  rchisq(100, 2),
  rchisq(100, 3),
  rchisq(100, 5), times=1000L)
ggplot2::autoplot(tm)
```

creates the following plot:
[image]

The plots are created by `geom_violin`. A violin plot is a mirrored density plot used to display a continuous distribution.

**Edit** By request of the OP here are some more details:

`tm` is an object of class `microbenchmark`, a data frame containing the results of 5000 single benchmark runs (5 expression x 1000 repetitions each). For more details, please, see the *Value* section of the help page `?microbenchmark`.

When this object is printed, a summary of the results is given:

```
print(tm)
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr    min     lq      mean median      uq       max neval
# rchisq(100, 0)  2.266  2.644  3.180188  2.644  3.0210    57.393  1000
# rchisq(100, 1) 16.614 19.257 21.412456 20.012 20.7675    80.048  1000
# rchisq(100, 2)  9.063 12.839 15.289609 14.349 15.8590   151.410  1000
# rchisq(100, 3)  8.307 12.460 16.291712 13.593 15.1040  1449.913  1000
# rchisq(100, 5)  7.929 11.706 26.683478 13.593 16.0475 11920.243  1000
```

Both `autoplot` and `print` are methods which are defined for objects of class `microbenchmark` and will not work as expected when applied to an ordinary data frame like `benchResult`.

### 2. Plot of `benchResult`

You can also plot your benchmark results using

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(benchResult, aes(x = forcats::fct_inorder(test), y = elapsed, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("test")
```

to produce this chart:

[image]

Please, note the call to `forcats::fct_inorder()` which reorders the levels of the factor in the same order as the values appeared in `benchResult$test`. This is required, as `ggplot2` uses factors for discrete variables and the default order of levels is alphabetically which would plot the tests in the order s1, s10, s2, s3, ... along the x-axis.

Comment: Could you bit more specify the solution of using `microbenchmark` package where using data.frame of benchmark results ? Still confused about your part-one solution. Thank you very much :)